# Undefined variables in Perl subroutines

Tags: perl, variables, subroutine

I am new to Perl and would like some help in understanding subroutines. In subroutines, is it the case that some variables will always be undefined? Is this because variables in subroutines are private? And so what if I wanted to then define said previously undefined variable, how would I go about doing that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should review http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html it will answer your question as well as provide additional helpful insight to programming with perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in Perl are not private, but they can have a limited scope. Such as when declaring them with `my` inside a subroutine. The arguments to the subroutine are stored in the variable `@_`.

```
do_stuff($foo, $bar);

sub do_stuff {
    my ($first, $second) = @_;   # direct assignment
    print "First: $first, Second: $second\n";
}
```

The `my` declaration makes the variables lexically scoped to the surrounding block `{ ... }`, which means they are protected, and they go out of scope when execution leaves the block.

Arguments to subroutines can also be accessed with the array functions `shift` and `pop`, which is commonly seen in Perl code:

```
sub do_stuff {
    my $first   = shift;
    my $second) = shift;
```

This does the same thing, except that it also removes the elements from the `@_` array.

Read more:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Answer (score 2):

In raw, unmitigated Perl, variables are *global* in scope. That is, they exist in your program from where you define them to the end of the script. Also, in Perl, variables spring into existence when you use them with an undefined value. In strings, this is treated as a null string. In numbers, it's treated as a zero.

Thus, in a subroutine, if you defined a variable in your main program, it's defined in your subroutine:

```
$foo = "Hello";
call_sub();

sub call_sub {
    print "$foo\n";
}
```

That will print "Hello".

However, no one should ever use Perl in this mode because it's so easy to have errors:

```
$name = "Bob"
print "Hello $Name!\n";
```

Whoops! I used `$name` when I defined it, and `$Name` when I used it. Plus, you don't want such global variables. Otherwise, your subroutines may overwrite your main program variables. Makes it really, really hard to write large complex programs.

In order to get around this, you are highly encouraged to put these two lines in your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

The `use warnings;` will issue a wide variety of warnings such as uninitialzed variables being treated as strings and numbers.

The `use strict;` makes even a bigger change. To put it simply (and incorrectly), `use strict` forces you to *declare* your variables before you can use them.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $name = "Bob"
print "Hello $Name\n";
```

This program won't work because `$Name` was never declared (you declare variables with the `my` keyword). You can see how that will prevent errors.

However, declaring these types of variables are known as lexically *scoped* variables. That is, they can go in and out of existence. If a variable is defined in a *block*, it will be undefined once outside of a *block*. Think of a block as the curly braces:

Subroutines are a block

```
sub foo {  # Curly brace starts the block
   ...
}          # Curly brace ends the block
```

This means if you define a variable in a subroutine, it's only in that subroutine.

Also, `while` and `for` loops are blocks:

```
for my $foo ( @foo_list ) {   # The variable $foo is only defined in this loop
   ...
}                             # End of block and end of loop

while ( my $foo = <@foo_list> ) {   # Again, $foo is only in this block
   ...
}                                   # End of the block

if ( $foo == $bar )   {        # Another block
   my $foo = 1;                # $foo is defined in the block
}                              # $foo is no longer defined
```

You can even use just curly braces:

```
my $foo = 1;
print "$foo\n"                # Prints 1
{
    my $foo = 2;              # Redefines $foo it's a different $foo!
    print "$foo\n"            # Prints 2
}                             # End of block, $foo in block is now out of scope
print "$foo\n";               # Prints 1 because the original $foo is in scope.
```

Let's look at this:

```
my $foo = 2;
my $bar = 5;
print "$foo\n";              # Prints 2
call_sub(5);                 # Prints "Foo is 5!"
print $foo\n";               # Prints 2

sub call_sub {
    my $foo = shift;         # Different $foo from main program!
    print "Foo is $foo!\n";
    print "Bar is $bar\n";   # Will print "Bar is 5" because $bar is in scope
}                            # Subroutine's $foo falls out of scope
```

As you can see, `$bar` was defined before I called the subroutine and so it's defined in the subroutine and still in scope. However, The `$foo` in my subroutine was redeclared, and remains until the end of the subroutine and falls out of scope. Thus, my subroutine's use of `$foo` won't interfere with my main program.

So, in answer to your question:

- Always use `use strict;`. This will force you to declare variables before they can be used.
- Variables are not defined until declared with `my`.
- Variables can have a limited scope where they live and breath. This can be very useful. Don't sit there and declare all variables at the beginning of your program with `my` like you would do in Pascal. Declare them where they are used, and let them fall out of scope when they're not needed.
- Subroutine variables are not *private* because a Subroutine can use an already declared variable. This is a *bad idea* because it allows a subroutine to override the value of a variable in your main program. So, always declare all of your subroutine variables with `my` to be safe.
- Use `use warnings;` to warn you when you forgot to define a variable you're trying to use.

---

And finally, I lied, but for a very good reason. Variables in Perl are a wee bit (a lot) more complex than I presented. You have the concept of *name space*, package variables, and a way to *localize* variables are aren't even local. Even people who work with Perl for years have a hard time understanding the ramifications.

`use strict;` doesn't really force you to declare variables. It forces you to either use lexically scoped variables which you declare with `my` or use *fully qualified variable names* for *package* variables (or use `our` to declare those).

However, in the end, `use strict;` does in a way force you to declare a variable since 99% of the variables you will use in Perl will be declared with `my`. When you learn more about Perl, you can learn a bit more about that other 1%.

For more information, take a look at [PerlSub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) about using `my` for *private variables*, and the take a look at [PerlMod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) for a full discussion about *package variables*, using *local*, and (how could I forget!) the newly introduced *state* variables.

Answer (score 1):

In general variables are defined with the my command (technically there is also some other ones like our and local but i never use them).

To define a variable type:

```
my $variable
```

if you do this in a subroutine it will make the variable you need.  Its often a good idea to use the strict directive in your code:

```
use strict
```

this will give you some warnings when you are forgetting to define things.

Comment: `my $variable` does not "define a variable type". It declares a variable.